# How to matches two records using ENTRY in progress 4GL?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I have written a program for matching two records. If its matching then i need to have a message "Matched" but the problem here is I don't get any idea about how to matching. Let me share my program

```
DEFINE VARIABLE cPos AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE tt_data NO-UNDO
      FIELD cPosition AS CHARACTER FORMAT "X(60)"
      FIELD cEndCode  AS CHARACTER
      FIELD cShotCode AS CHARACTER. 

CREATE tt_data.
ASSIGN
tt_data.cPosition ="S$$$^^^^^^^^^^$$$^^^MC^^^^^^^^^^^^R^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^"
tt_data.cEndCode =  10
tt_data.cShotCode = "S".

CASE tt_data.cEndCode:

WHEN 10 THEN DO:
cPos = 1.
END.

WHEN 20 THEN DO:
cPos = 2.
END.
.
.
.
WHEN 600 THEN DO:
cPos = 60
END.

END CASE.

FIND FIRST tt_date WHERE tt_data.cShotCode = SUBSTRING(tt_data.cPosition,cPos,1) NO-LOCK NO-ERROR. 

DISPLAY tt_data.cShotCode. /* Displayed Value is S */
```

If you see tt_datacEndCode value is 10 which means its pointing ENTRY 1 of tt_data.cPosition (i.e. S).

When 20 then its for ENTRY 2 like wise i want to get up to 600 (i.e. tt_datacEndCode = 60).

The problem here is I cannot have WHEN statement up to 600. So Could you please help this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the example that you have shown you could eliminate the CASE statement and simply replace it with:

```
cPos = integer( tt_data.cEndCode / 10 ).
```

(assuming that, as shown, cEndCode is always a multiple of 10 and the desired cPos is 1/10th of that value.)

Thus:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE cPos AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE tt_data NO-UNDO
      FIELD cPosition AS CHARACTER FORMAT "X(60)"
      FIELD cEndCode  AS CHARACTER
      FIELD cShotCode AS CHARACTER. 

CREATE tt_data.
ASSIGN
tt_data.cPosition ="S$$$^^^^^^^^^^$$$^^^MC^^^^^^^^^^^^R^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^"
tt_data.cEndCode =  10
tt_data.cShotCode = "S".

cPos = integer( tt_data.cEndCode / 10 ).

FIND FIRST tt_date WHERE tt_data.cShotCode = SUBSTRING(tt_data.cPosition,cPos,1) NO-LOCK NO-ERROR. 

DISPLAY tt_data.cShotCode. /* Displayed Value is S */
```

Comment: I would agree, but recommend replacing the `FIND FIRST` with a `FOR FIRST` whilst dropping the `NO-ERROR` at the end. That creates a block and only runs the `DISPLAY` statement if a record was successfully found, and saves the error handling logic around it.

Comment: I'm no fan of pointlessly throwing FIRST on every FIND but decided to hold my tongue for some reason.  FOR FIRST is another can of worms - although I do like the part about it forming a block and only running when true.

Comment: Will it going to be loop? because tt_data.cPosition value is not same always. It might change. So we have to involve each record from tt_data.cPosition to all checking case i means upto tt_data.EndCode = 600.